# dc.js average value over the summed field

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have the following data array:

```
  ID   Name   Number  
 ---- ------ -------- 
   1   G           1  
   1   G           2  
   1   F           3
```

I want to do the following conversion to calculate the average, but I don’t know how to do it.

```
  ID   Name   Number_sum  
 ---- ------ ------------ 
   1   G               3  
   1   F               3
```

after summing calculate the average

```
  ID   Number_avg  
 ---- ------------ 
   1            3
```

If you do not pre-sum, then the average value is calculated incorrectly:

```
  ID   Number_avg  
 ---- ------------ 
   1            2
```

I want to calculate the average value for each ID, but with an even field "Name".

Next, I plan to build a graph for each ID. I have a road identifier - 1. This road consists of 2 sections: G and F. Moreover, section G is divided into 2 more small sections, 1 and 2 km each.

If we consider the usual average value, then we get the average value over the maximum section of the value - a sub-section of the road. But I want to make a calculation based on the average value of the road sections.

[image: example of calculations in spreadsheet]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>dc.js</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>


    
</head>
<body>
<div id ="test"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//dc.js
 var inlineND = new dc.NumberDisplay("#test");
 
//data
var array1 = [
            {"ID": 1, "Name": "G", "Number": 1},
            {"ID": 1, "Name": "G", "Number": 2},
            {"ID": 1, "Name": "F", "Number": 3}
            ];

var make_calc = function() {
            var ndx                 = crossfilter(array1), //
            Dimension               = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.ID;}),
            DimensionGroup          = Dimension.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);           
            
            function reduceAdd(p, v) {
            ++p.count;
            p.total += v.Number;
            return p;
            }

            function reduceRemove(p, v) {
            --p.count;
            p.total -= v.Number;
            return p;
            }

            function reduceInitial() {
            return {count: 0, total: 0};
            }
            
            inlineND
                .group(DimensionGroup)
                .valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value.count > 0 ? p.value.total / p.value.count : 0; });
                
            dc.renderAll();
            //console.log(DimensionGroup);
};

make_calc();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to show your code because it is unclear even what libraries you are using. I think I recognize this as a crossfilter question because you reference dc.js, but I wouldn't be able to figure that out from the text of your question. Also you don't show how you are computing the average incorrectly. I don't know what a pre-sum is either.

Comment: I've removed some vague tags that often bring hater close-vote people, and added [crossfilter]. If this is a [javascript] question and not a [crossfilter] question, feel free to change them back.

Comment: @Gordon 
I added the code with the libraries that I use. In this example, a simple calculation of the average value for a single value of "A" is given.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code, that helps a lot. There are still a couple of things I don't understand. Do you want to display the average for each Name, or the average overall? Your table displays the *sum* for each Name, not any *average* as far as I can tell.

Comment: Your code bins the rows by ID, and determines the average is 2.0 (3 rows, total 6), which looks correct. If you change the dimension to Name, it produces an average of 1.5 for the first bin (G, 2 rows, total 3), which is also correct. I guess I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the sums by Name, and then display the average of those sums?

Comment: I want to calculate the average value for each ID, but with an even field "Name". Next, I plan to build a graph for each ID.


I have a road identifier - 1. This road consists of 2 sections: G and F. Moreover, section G is divided into 2 more small sections, 1 and 2 km each.

If we consider the usual average value, then we get the average value over the maximum section of the value - a sub-section of the road.
But I want to make a calculation based on the average value of the road sections.

Comment: Are you able to edit your question to add the new info? It's better not to overuse comments on SO.

Comment: @Gordon https://imgur.com/download/C2drJRm/

Accordingly, I want to calculate the average value to the level I need, having previously "summed up" more detailed values.

Comment: Won't you please edit your question so that it contains all the pertinent information, rather than adding all these comments? This is too messy and hard to follow.

Comment: alright, I've edited your question for you. still not completely sure i understand it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to calculate the average, taking into account the "Name" field, it is necessary to consider the unique occurrence of this field in the reduce function. As a result, when calculating the average value, divide the sum of values ​​by the number of unique values ​​in the "Name" field

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>dc.js</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id ="test"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//dc.js
 var inlineND = new dc.NumberDisplay("#test");
 
//data
var array1 = [
            {"ID": 1, "Name": "G", "Number": 1},
            {"ID": 1, "Name": "G", "Number": 2},
            {"ID": 1, "Name": "F", "Number": 3}
            ];

var make_calc = function() {
            var ndx                 = crossfilter(array1), //
            Dimension               = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.ID;}),
            DimensionGroup          = Dimension.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);           
            
                       
            function reduceAdd(p, v) {
            ++p.count;
            p.total += v.Number;
                if(v.Name in p.Names){
                    p.Names[v.Name] += 1
                }
                else{
                    p.Names[v.Name] = 1;
                    p.Name_count++;
                };
            return p;
            }

            function reduceRemove(p, v) {
            --p.count;
            p.total -= v.Number;
                p.Names[v.Name]--;
                if(p.Names[v.Name] === 0){
                    delete p.Names[v.Name];
                    p.Name_count--;
                };
            return p;
            }

            function reduceInitial() {
            return {count: 0, total: 0, Name_count: 0, Names: {}};
            }
            
            inlineND
                .group(DimensionGroup)
                .valueAccessor(function(p) { return p.value.Name_count > 0 ? p.value.total / p.value.Name_count : 0; });
                
            dc.renderAll();
            //console.log(DimensionGroup);
};

make_calc();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I think this has the same effect as my answer, since the number of unique keys will be the number of bins in a dimension on that field.

Comment: I guess the difference is that this will calculate the average of the Names for each ID, whereas mine calculates the average over all Names.

Comment: @Gordon All right. In my decision, it is possible to enter the average value in the context of id, taking into account the number of unique "Name" values.

Accordingly, in future I will probably use this code for graphs, where the "Name" field is not the maximum data granularity.
As a result, no matter how much detailed data there is at the input. You can always calculate the average value to the level of detail of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but are you looking for something like this?

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 1, name: 'G', number: 1},
  {id: 2, name: 'G', number: 2},
  {id: 3, name: 'F', number: 3}
]

const res = arr.reduce((acc, e) => {
  const idx = acc.findIndex(x => x.name === e.name)
  if (idx !== -1) {
    acc[idx].number += e.number
  } else {
    acc.push(e)
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: This is why I fixed the tags. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand, but if you want to group by Name, sum, and and then take the average of all groups, you could put your dimension on Name and use regular `reduceSum`:

```
            var ndx                 = crossfilter(array1), //
            Dimension               = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Name;}),
            DimensionGroup          = Dimension.group().reduceSum(d => d.Number);
```

Then pass a "fake groupAll" which returns all the rows from the group to the number display, and calculate the average in the value accessor:

```
                .group({value: () => DimensionGroup.all()})
                .valueAccessor(a => a.length === 0 ? 0 : d3.sum(a, ({value}) => value) / a.length);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>dc.js</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/js/dc.js"></script>


    
</head>
<body>
<div id ="test"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//dc.js
 var inlineND = new dc.NumberDisplay("#test");
 
//data
var array1 = [
            {"ID": 1, "Name": "G", "Number": 1},
            {"ID": 1, "Name": "G", "Number": 2},
            {"ID": 1, "Name": "F", "Number": 3}
            ];

var make_calc = function() {
            var ndx                 = crossfilter(array1), //
            Dimension               = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.Name;}),
            DimensionGroup          = Dimension.group().reduceSum(d => d.Number);

            
            inlineND
                .group({value: () => DimensionGroup.all()})
                .valueAccessor(a => a.length === 0 ? 0 : d3.sum(a, ({value}) => value) / a.length);
                
            dc.renderAll();
            //console.log(DimensionGroup);
};

make_calc();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```